# Static charge in an accelerated frame

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, special-relativity, electrostatics

In special relativity the metric of an accelerated frame is
$$ds^2= (1-2 a_j x^j)dt^2 + 2 \Omega_{m j}x^j dx^m dt + \eta_{ml}dx^m dx^j$$
where the sums over latin indices go from 1 to 3.
Let's suppose we have a static charge in the origin of our coordinate system. Is there an approximate solution of the Maxwell equations for that point charge?

Comment: The charge is sitting at fixed spacelike coordinates in the accelerated frame.

Comment: The metric that you wrote is generally non-flat. For $\Omega=0$ the Kottler-Møller metric would be recovered if $g_{tt}$ element is $-(1-a x)^\color{red}{2}$.